# Facebook Graph Explorer returning a different account id than PHP SDK

Tags: angularjs, facebook

I'm getting the information of my account using `Facebook PHP SDK V4` but first I'm getting de access token from a angularjs app using the cordova plugin [ngCordova OAuth](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/blob/master/README.md), so on PHP I'm geting the account id `798776790185364`.

When I'm getting the account id from `Graph Explorer` at [developers.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com) I'm geting `100001591518421`.

Comment: That is by design. You are getting something called app scoped user ids.

Comment: In Graph API Explorer, switch it to your app from the dropdown list at the top …

Comment: @CBroe thats correct, I changed in the dropdown for the same app that I'm using on PHP and works. If you create an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called app-scoped user ids. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

> With app-scoped IDs, the ID for the same user will be different between apps.